# Как реализовать алгоритм заполнения списка длиной N из чисел, не кратных 3

Tags: python

Нужна последовательность из N чисел, которые не делятся нацело на 3. Например, при
`N = 10: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]` (исключаем `3, 6, 9, 12` и т.д.).

```
1<=N<=10^6
```

```
N = int(input())
c = [x for x in range(1, N+1) if x % 3 != 0]
```

Изначально я просто попытался создать и заполнить список значениями, которые удовлетворяют условию, но столкнулся с проблемой, что при этом я потерял некоторые числа. При N = 10, вместо c[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14], я получил c[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]

Вопрос: Как реализовать алгоритм, который создает список длиной N и заполняет его значениями n, удовлетворяющими условию n % 3 != 0, без потери промежуточных чисел?

Comment: ты забыл 1) попытаться решить задачу самостоятельно, 2) задать вопрос. Тут не выполняют хотелки типа "нужно". Если нужно, то бери и делай.

Comment: Добавьте вашу попытку решения, мы подскажем, что не так и как исправить

Comment: Последовательность `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1]` (единица повторена `N` раз) подходит? Тогда ответ `[1] * N`.

Comment: Вы заполняете список значениями от 1 до N, в этом и проблема. Стоило бы сделать так: `c = [int(input("Enter:")) for x in range(0, N) if x % 3 != 0]`

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас отрезок `[1; N]`, то есть вы заполняете список числами до 10, которые не делятся на 3.

Comment: Я думаю, что вам нужно сделать так: `c = [x for x in range(1, 10**6+1) if x % 3 != 0]`

Comment: Мне не нужен полный список со всеми числами до N=10^6. Я хочу сделать алгоритм заполнения списка длиной N значениями n, удовлетворяющими условию n % 3 != 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как я понимаю вам нужно `N` чисел, которые не делятся на 3, поэтому тут помог бы бесконечный цикл `while`, который бы шел до тех пор, пока нужное кол-во не будет достигнуто

```
res = []
value = 0

while True:
    if value % 3 != 0:
        res.append(value)
        if len(res) == N:
            break;
    value += 1
```

по идее можно сделать всё и за 1 цикл `for`:

```
res = [v for v in range(M) if v % 3 != 0]
```

но тогда нужно вычислить `M`, при котором будет набрано строго `N` не делящихся на 3 чисел, типа:

```
M = N * 4 // 3 # Приближённая формула, точная учитывает делимость N на 3
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает!

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input('N: '))
out, i = [], 1
while len(out) < N:
    if i % 3:
        out.append(i)
    i += 1
print(out)
```

```
N: 12
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17]
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает!